# How to remove columns in group by Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis

Trying to remove a column of data that is no longer needed.

I have tried to use .drop and it isn't doing anything that I can tell.

```
df=df.groupby(df['Distributor'])['Tickets Sold'].sum()
df1=df[df.div(df.sum()).lt(0.01)]
df2=df.drop(df1.index)
yourdf=pd.concat([df2,pd.Series(df1.sum(),index=['Others'])])

yourdf = yourdf.sort_values(ascending=False)
print(yourdf)
yourdf2 = yourdf.drop(columns=['Tickets Sold'])
print(yourdf2)
```

Instead of this.

```
20th Century Fox      141367982
Focus Features         18799261
Lionsgate              75834308
Paramount Pictures     86302817
STX Entertainment      22606674
Sony Pictures         102746480
Universal             159556790
Walt Disney           315655340
Warner Bros.          216426845
Others                 74618013
```

Then into this.

```
Walt Disney           315655340
Warner Bros.          216426845
Universal             159556790
20th Century Fox      141367982
Sony Pictures         102746480
Paramount Pictures     86302817
Lionsgate              75834308
Others                 74618013
STX Entertainment      22606674
Focus Features         18799261
```

I need this.

```
Walt Disney          
Warner Bros.         
Universal             
20th Century Fox      
Sony Pictures         
Paramount Pictures     
Lionsgate              
Others                 
STX Entertainment      
Focus Features
```

Comment: is your dataframe just the two columns?

Comment: dataframe is a total of 6 columns and 680 rows.

Comment: you can just do df2 = df[['namecolumn']] if you want it as a dataframe, or df2 = df['namecolumn'] if you want it as a Series.

Comment: @BenPap how would i use this in my code above?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `axis=1` to tell it you want to drop a column rather than an index.

```
yourdf.drop('Tickets Sold', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(yourdf)
#           Distributor
# 0    20th Century Fox
# 1      Focus Features
# 2           Lionsgate
# 3  Paramount Pictures
# 4   STX Entertainment
# 5       Sony Pictures
# 6           Universal
# 7         Walt Disney
# 8         Warner Bros
# 9              Others
```

If you really want to preserve `yourdf` and have another `yourdf2` then

```
yourdf2 = yourdf.drop('Tickets Sold', axis=1)
```

Comment: How can i do this from the yourdf, not the df itself and also keeping it in the greatest to least sort.

Comment: It works the same for any dataframe that has that column in it

Comment: When i do that, i get No axis named 1 for object type <class 'type'>

Comment: can you update your post so it's a little more clear which print statements are yielding which output? I'm not sure how you're applying the code above.

Comment: there are 144 distributors and 680 movies, the code takes only the distributors with the total amount of tickets sold for every movie that is made from that distributor and then only posting the distributors that take up more than 1% of total ticket sales and adds all others to others.

Comment: Then I need to rearrange those from greatest to least, that solves one question and then remove the column of tickets and only have the names or just only take the names out of the yourdf and be able to post that for another question.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comments and reading your code, I'm thinking the behind the scenes issue is you're casting/recasting variables too much. This is resulting in overwriting/loosing what you're looking for when you need it. No worries, I'm sure you're in a Phase-1 stage of your project and testing things. But I wanted to point that out in case. You can always navigate around this issue using the `inplace=True` keyword argument.

In any case, as Brian Cohan said, you need to delcare an axis with `axis=1`.

Taking your code, it would look like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(df['Distributor'])['Tickets Sold'].sum()); display(df)
df = df.sort_values(by="Tickets Sold", ascending=False); display(df)
df = df.drop("Tickets Sold", axis = 1); display(df)
# See here ------------------^
```

```
|--------------------+--------------|
|                    | Tickets Sold |
|--------------------+--------------|
| Distributor        |              |
|--------------------+--------------|
| 20th Century Fox   |    141367982 |
| Focus Features     |     18799261 |
| Lionsgate          |     75834308 |
| Paramount Pictures |     86302817 |
| STX Entertainment  |     22606674 |
| Sony Pictures      |    102746480 |
| Universal          |    159556790 |
| Walt Disney        |    315655340 |
| Warner Bros.       |    216426845 |
| Others             |     74618013 |
|--------------------+--------------|

|--------------------+--------------|
|                    | Tickets Sold |
|--------------------+--------------|
| Distributor        |              |
|--------------------+--------------|
| Walt Disney        |    315655340 |
| Warner Bros.       |    216426845 |
| Universal          |    159556790 |
| 20th Century Fox   |    141367982 |
| Sony Pictures      |    102746480 |
| Paramount Pictures |     86302817 |
| Lionsgate          |     75834308 |
| Others             |     74618013 |
| STX Entertainment  |     22606674 |
| Focus Features     |     18799261 |
|--------------------+--------------|

|--------------------+
|                    |
|--------------------+
| Distributor        |
|--------------------+
| Walt Disney        |
| Warner Bros.       |
| Universal          |
| 20th Century Fox   |
| Sony Pictures      |
| Paramount Pictures |
| Lionsgate          |
| Others             |
| STX Entertainment  |
| Focus Features     |
|--------------------|
```

Comment: df=df.groupby(df['Distributor'])['Tickets Sold'].sum()
df1=df[df.div(df.sum()).lt(0.01)]
df2=df.drop(df1.index)
yourdf=pd.concat([df2,pd.Series(df1.sum(),index=['Others'])])

yourdf = yourdf.sort_values(ascending=False)
print(yourdf)
yourdf2 = yourdf.drop('Tickets Sold', axis=1)
print(yourdf2)

Comment: how can i implement what you did in the code I have or if i replace all of this code with yours it will work?

Comment: because i am using yourdf and yourdf2 to hold the original df for other uses and your df and yourdf2 as ways to solve other questions

Comment: Give me 5 minutes to run a few tests and see what I can do for you. Be right back.

Comment: Ok, if you're trying to have one df for a variety of questions, I would recast df's as the questions come. df1, df1, df3, etc. If you're trying to use these values elsewhere, you might have a problem because they're index values. So you'll need to pull them out in some kind of array with df.index(). You can replace what I did in your code, but that doesn't mean it will work if we're not answering/asking the right questions, which I think is the problem here.

Comment: how would i end up doing that?

Comment: To declare different df's for different questions you can do ```df_q1 = df```, ```df_q2 = df```, etc. But, be careful not to overwrite ```df```. To take the index values out into their own array you can do ```distributors = np.array(df.index.values)```. This stores them in a numpy array ```distributors```, which is taken from ```df``` in the order which they appear in the index. Again, be sure to not overwrite variables.

Comment: Wanna help this guy out too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55943367/how-to-make-a-list-of-elements-ordered-from-greatest-to-least-based-off-the-data